# Silverlight component not loaded on MSCRM 2011 form

Tags: silverlight, crm

I have a section with silverlight component that is visible depending on the status of records.

- If I set that section's Visible By Default = true and hide it in some cases => it works.
  But I could not set it Visible by default = true because the screen loading is NOT smooth (the silverlight component appears and disapears)
- Alternately, I hide it by default (Visible by default = false) and only show it if needed (jscript - onload)
  => it does NOT work!! The silverlight component is empty! I've already tried a very simple silverlight component with just a simple label, but it's still the same issue.

I guess it's a problem of loading siverlight webresource on MSCRM 2011...

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem, I think it's a bug in CRM. In my onload, I add it

var s = document.getElementById("WebResource_silverlight");

s.style.height = "100%"

and then it's visible again :)